# LabelFor not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to create labels dynamically according to the number of items in a collection.

My model is passed to my view fine, however when iterating through the collection - i can't get the labels to display the values of the list of string.

For example i am using the following code:

```
  @foreach (var ac in model.myClass.listofstring)
           {
               @Html.LabelFor(a => ac)
           }
```

If the collection has 4 items, the above code will output "acacacac"
I would like it to output 4 labels, with the string values of the items in the list.

I have also tried `@Html.LabelFor(a => ac.ToString())` and  `@Html.LabelFor(a => ac.ToString)` but the view then doesn't render.

I know the values are in the list as i can access them in my controller. The value of `test` is what i want in my view.

```
   foreach (var ac in myClass.listofstring)
       {
          var test = ac.ToString();
       }
```

I have also tried this, with no luck:

```
   @for (var i = 0; i < model.myClass.listofstring.Count(); i++)
           {
               @Html.LabelFor(a => a[i])
           }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Label isn't displaying the value of the item, it's just displaying its name. Use @Html.DisplayFor instead

Comment: As simple as that.. Thanks!

Comment: I'm happy that I could help :) Please accept my answer if it works :)